# Deploying Revel (Golang) Using Dokku

Tags: go, revel, dokku

Has anyone tried deploying a Revel app using Dokku?

I tried "https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-dokku-one-click-digitalocean-image-to-run-a-go-app" and it deployed successfully.

However, when I try a new Revel app, it gives me this error

```
remote: mv: cannot stat `/build/app/.heroku/g/bin/*': No such file or directory
```

This is the .godir that I created:

```
myappname
```

This is the Procfile:

```
myappname
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since Revel is a web app (receiving incoming HTTP traffic), you need to declare a *web* process type in your *Procfile*, i.e.:

```
web: myappname ## Procfile requires a Unix process declaration
```

This tells Dokku what command to run to start the web process on the server -- in this case *myappname.go* in your project root.
Leave off the *.go* file extension in the Procfile.

Dokku is a "Docker powered mini-Heroku" so Heroku's support docs are relevant:

> The unix process model is a simple and powerful abstraction for running server-side programs. Applied to web apps, the process model gives us a unique way to think about dividing our workloads and scaling up over time. The Heroku Cedar stack uses the process model for web, worker and all other types of dynos.
>   -- from [Process Types and the Procfile - Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)

Note that the standard Go Buildpack for Heroku/Dokku needs either a [Godeps](https://github.com/tools/godep) directory, or the deprecated method of including a **.godir** file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [revel buildpack](https://github.com/revel/heroku-buildpack-go-revel) instead of the Go one. The buildpack will generate the `Procfile` for you.

Be sure to:

- Add a `.env` file with this in your project: `BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/revel/heroku-buildpack-go-revel`.
- Add a `.godir` file with the argument you use to run your app, e.g. `github.com/yourcompany/yourrepo`.